# Accidently sent TRC20 Tether to an ERC20 wallet, what do I do?

Tags: wallets, network, wallet-transfer, usdt, usdc

Used Kraken to Send TRC20 to an ERC20 wallet and i do not see funds in erc20 wallet

trans id: 0x60f487f0e36b8be315b3955188bba8b3e62ab60b8f41e1fea256a304ecf0acee

Answer (score 0):

When you say you used Kraken to send - I assume you were trying to withdraw the Tether to your own wallet? It looks to me like you sent $1,196.45 worth of Tether to 0xf8854039e9a8ce16a8fab32df6b451978e8eb0fa which then quickly forwards to:
0xeb5ed670e8a512a7ecd34188f8b5756dba23d1c7

See:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7?a=0xf8854039e9a8ce16a8fab32df6b451978e8eb0fa